# Copy value to Clipboard via right click with menu when mouse right click

Tags: c#, wpf, clipboard

Please this event:

```
private void pieLegend_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var hoveredItem = this.pieLegend.Items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsHovered);
    Clipboard.SetText(hoveredItem.Title);
}
```

This event fired after `PicChart` Legend title right click.
When mouse is over and right click the `Legend` title is copy but this is not obvious because no menu is opened so is i possible to add the option Copy to the right click before the value is copy to `Clipboard` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a `ContextMenuStrip` with a `"Copy"` `ToolStripMenuItem` to your form and set it as the `ContextMenuStrip` property of your `PicChart` control. This automatically works as a context menu, so you do not need to check any right-click event.

You just need to put your code in the `Click` event of the `ToolStripMenuItem` inside your menu strip then.

Comment: That's what you do in the WinForms designer, there's no code at all. Everything related with code is to copy your two lines of code to the `Click` event of your menu strip item.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the misunderstanding. Anyway, then just select your PicChart in the designer, find the `ContextMenu` property and click `New`. Add a control to the context menu and use its `Click` event. Everything else is like I explained for WinForms.